# What is that decommissioned plane near Nadirgul Airfield?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This is a decommissioned plane that I found at my place. I'm guessing it is a Dakota DC-47.

The plane is placed near a small airstrip called Nadirgul (name of the location), which lies in the outskirts of the city Hyderabad, India

[image: Anonymous aircraft]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is right, this model is a C-47A-85-DL Skytrain, a variant of the "Dak" DC-3 selected by the US Army Air Force in 1941 as its standard transport aircraft.

[image]
<sup>Image from [Le Bourget Air & Space Museum](https://www.museeairespace.fr/aller-plus-haut/collections/douglas-c-47a-skytrain-dakota/)</sup>

It has been early used by Allied forces to [drop paratroopers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TkyCqUJhig) and equipment or to tow gliders behind the coastline for the D-Day and operation Overlord.

[image]
<sup>C47 from [439th Troop Carrier Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/439th_Operations_Group) and [Waco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waco_CG-4) with their [invasion stripes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_stripes) taking off from England for Utah Beach, June 1944 ([source](http://www.dday.center/d-day-technology-c47-skytrain-dakota.html))</sup>

It had a long history and was everywhere until the end of the war and in the post-war conflicts, e.g. many of them participated to the Berlin Airlift:

[image]
<sup>C47s unloading at Templehof airport in Berlin, 1948. [Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/C-47s_at_Tempelhof_Airport_Berlin_1948.jpg)</sup>

Differences with the DC-3 include:

- cargo door
- hoist attachment
- strengthened floor
- shortened tail cone for glider-towing shackles
- astrodome in the cabin roof.

You said the aircraft was standing at Nadargul airstrip. This information has been very useful to find the exact aircraft. It happens the aircraft did have a long story, throughout eras of war and peace, linking people of many countries:

- A C-47A-85-DL airframe with c/n 20012, is manufactured in Long Beach, California, by Douglas ([source](http://www.abcdlist.nl/douglas_longbeach_03.html)) for the USAF (registration 43-15546).
- In 1946, right after the war, it becomes the French government property (F-BAXK) operated for cargo flights under Air France colors.
- [Sold in 1950](https://francearchives.fr/en/facomponent/5c77a066f0e16da37779f8b0a8d45345619dd2dd) to Portuguese government to be operated from Lisbon by Aéro Portuguesa (CS-ADB).
- 1953: Leaving Europe when sold to Lebanon, operated by Air Liban (OD-ABQ).
- Finally moving further eastwards to India, bought by Kasturi and Sons (VT-DTS) to deliver *[The Indu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hindu)* newspaper in distant areas until it is decommissioned and transferred to Nadargul where it is used now by the Flytech Aviation Academy for ground training ([source](http://warbirds.in/oldhtml/wbhyd.html)).

<sup>([Source](http://aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=58591))</sup>

**A movie star**

This aircraft is seen in the 1965 Hindi feature film, [Gumnaam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumnaam) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5sTIDeIaKs)):

[image]

**Stamps in Israel**

The aircraft was used for the first aerial mail sacks sent in 1948 from Israel to European countries, when it belonged to Air France. Two stamps commemorated in 2008 "60 Years of Friendship between Israel and France":

[image]

> On June 9, 1948 an Air France DC3 airplane, registration number
>   F-BAXK, landed Haifa, flown by pilot Georges Bernard and two crew
>   members: communication technician Mr. Sortais and mechanic Mr. Boutet.
>   The plane made an interim stop in Bucharest while en route to Israel,
>   thus arriving with mail from both France and Romania. The plane
>   subsequently left Haifa on June 11 at 6:36 a.m., bearing mail to
>   France and other countries with which Israel had re-established postal
>   ties: Bulgaria, Holland, Hungary, Yugoslavia, Poland and Switzerland.
>   It also carried a mail sack bound for New York. After interim stop in
>   Cyprus, Greece Italy and Nice in southern France, the airplane took of
>   the next day towards its final destination, Le Bourget airport in
>   Paris, where it landed on June 12, 1948 at 11:01 a.m. and delivered its
>   mail sacks.

([Source](http://www.boeliem.com/content/2008/809.html))

Comment: That's plenty of information..... thankyou for your dedicated curiosity and exploration..... great work...!

Comment: Fantastic legwork, compiling this answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It is either a Douglas DC-2 or DC-3.

The difference between the two is the length and the wingspan: The DC-2 has a length of [19,1 meters (62,7 ft) and a wingspan of 25,9 meters (98,1 ft)](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-2) and the DC-3 had an length of [19,7 meters (64,3 ft) and a wingspan of 30,0 meters (98,4 ft)](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-3)

Since I can't really see the full length of the aircraft in your picture, if you roughly know the wingspan, you can identify the aircraft.

But if you really want to know which version it is (e.g C52, D-42) you should take a look on the wiki pages [(DC-2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-2#Variants) [(DC-3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_DC-3#Variants)

Comment: It's a DC3. The DC2 had landing lights in the nose cone.

Comment: @tj1000 it's hard to see on a picture this resolution, but I see some kind of light cone on the nose.

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis the DC2 has very pronounced protrusions on the underside of the nose for the lights which are missing in this aircraft. It also has a quite different shaped vertical stab (which is not visible of course in the photo). Unless it's some custom conversion of a DC2 using a DC3 nose cone, it's a DC3.